# WalletMultiButton only establishes a connection to Phantom wallet every other time

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I've been following along soldev course and I'm now starting to interact with a browser wallet [interact-with-wallets](https://soldev.app/course/interact-with-wallets). Problem is whenever I try to connect to a wallet it only connects after two clicks. The error on first click is the following: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'walletName' exceeded the quota.`

[image: error message]

The code I'm using:

```
import './App.css';
import {WalletContextProvider} from './components/WalletContextProvider';
import {PingButton} from './components/PingButton';
import AppBar from './AppBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <WalletContextProvider>
      {/* <AppBar /> */}
      {/* <PingButton /> */}
    </WalletContextProvider>
 )
}

export default App;
```

```
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-phantom'
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'
import { WalletModalProvider, WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui'
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js'
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css')

interface WalletContextProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode
}

export function WalletContextProvider({children}: WalletContextProviderProps) {
  const endpoint = clusterApiUrl('devnet')
  const wallets = [new PhantomWalletAdapter()]

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          <WalletMultiButton />
          {/* {children} */}
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  )
}
```

Following https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#ui-components led to the same error

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code. 
From the error it seems your local storage space is fully consumed, you can clear the local storage space. Also you can try running the app in another browser to be sure.